# syncrepl_message_to_entry: rid=002 mods check (objectClass: value #1 invalid per syntax)

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have a problem with my master master config database replication (i will add the data replication after this one). I am running on each master, openldap and freeradius. To have freeradius working with openldap, I created ldif schema on each server.

For info :
rid=001 is the master n1 and rid=002 is the master n2

When starting slapd on both servers, I get on the master n1 this error : `syncrepl_message_to_entry: rid=002 mods check (objectClass: value #1 invalid per syntax)`.
It seems to appear because loaded schemas between the two servers aren't the same.

I tried to make sure all schemas were the same :

- copied the .ldif file of the freeradius schema generated on the master n1 to the master n2 and loading it
- changed the configuration of the replication to add `schemachecking=off` (not working)

But when I `diff` the files containing the result of `ldapsearch -H ldapi:/// -x -s base -b "cn=subschema" +`, there is a few differences.

Note : The freeradius schema is working on both server, the command `radtest` is working (getting `Access-Accept`).

---

Does the problem come from the difference in cn=subschema between the two servers ?

How can I resolve the differences of the loaded schema between the two servers ?

Is ignoring the replication of the schema safe ? And how can I do it ?